# Add icon on "Related" question list that shows answered status

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, unanswered-questions, related-questions

When you're viewing a question, there's a list of "Related" questions on the right. I propose that a small icon be added to the titles that indicates if they're currently answered or not. I often use this list to jump from question to question, and if I can easily identify ones that are still unanswered, that's ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Very nice idea! The list of related questions is often very long and some further hints might be really beneficial for someone looking for answers (or questions).

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely we will do this, since we *want* people to explore related questions regardless of their status, or number of answers.

The only salient point is that the question has a strong relationship to the current question, based on

- title match
- tags match (heavily weighted)
- body text match

Comment: An item missing from the list is * links to the question currently being viewed

This would make a lot of sense to include, yes?

Comment: @Jeff: yes, Jeff, but you are actually discouraging us, I only stick to query searches, now, they are so much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

I've voted for this, but note that the current `Related Questions` feature gives you this when you start to ask a question. Another case of the [Related Questions being better than Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool).