# How do the "related question" suggestions work on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, related-questions, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are “related” questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected)

I'm working on a Stack Overflow-like answers site, and I'm trying to replicate the "related questions" feature. Is there a good way to use a title to find similar titles? I can do keyword searches with sphinx, but the results I'm getting aren't very useful most of the time.