# Can we have a full list of related questions?

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

When viewing a question, there is a list on the right that displays related questions. However, I suspect they do not display the full list of related questions since the size of the list seems to be fixed at 10.

Sometimes, I would like to have a more exhaustive list of related questions.
Could that feature be added? For example, a whole new page with a list of questions related to a particular question.

Comment: Considering the complexity of the search, I doubt it's feasible to get a full list. But if it is, it would be great!

Answer (score 5):

I like this request. I think it would make the most sense to have a link underneath the related questions that says "more related questions", in the same way that Hot Network Questions has a "more hot questions" link. This would allow the people who want to see them could have the option, but it wouldn't add any additional overhead for people who don't want to see them.

Example:

[image: Related questions example]

Answer (score 5):

I think this could be a search operator:

```
related:XXXXX
```

where "XXXXX" is the ID of the post.

So, `related:248469` would return all of the questions "related" to this question in the normal search results.

---

This is similar to `inquestion:XXXXX` and could even use `related:this` in the same way `inquestion:this` works.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Tags serves that purpose sufficiently. Sometime one question can be relevant to many topics.

You are right that related questions list around 10 question matching with word entered in title, I think Its sufficient for a brief idea. To see all the  related question user can visit the Tag section.

Comment: I get your point but I dont think they always do, because tags are sometimes too braod spectrum especially in the science sites. At any rate (being a computer programmer myself) it seems to be a trivial feature to add.

Comment: I don't think that they pick the list of related questions just by comparing tags. I think they do some kind of keyword search for that.

Comment: @user2277550 is right - [Essentially, it's a vocabulary search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20476/152859).