# One request/suggestion for Stack Exchange sites: should show related questions

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

I have one request/suggestion for Stack Exchange sites and that is: at the end/bottom of every question's answers, the site should suggest related questions (and their answers) to look into. It would be a great way for readers to gain insights about the subject.

Comment: like we have on the right hand side of this question under the heading Related?

Answer (score 10):

There's already a "Related" sidebar widget which does more or less what you describe. The questions there are chosen from the top questions in the tags on the current question, more details here: [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected)

You want them *under* the question's answers? No problem, just resize the browser window and they'll appear underneath:

[image]

Comment: Sorry sir I was not aware of this.