# Would a "Related network questions" list be possible and worthwhile?

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

The scopes of many sites overlap, e.g.:

- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/);
- [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/);
- [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), and [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/); and
- any language site with [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) and [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Currently the "Related" list of questions is restricted to questions for that particular site.  It seems natural to extend this to either:

- add an additional, short "Related network questions" list, or
- allow a limited number of off-site questions within the "Related" list, highlighting the site they're from, and maybe throttling the [tf-idf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected) for off-site questions.

My hope is that it can identify questions that are already asked on other sites ([cross-site duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)), and this knowledge can assist writing answers.

**Question**: Would a "Related network questions" list be possible and worthwhile?

Comment: You could potentially decide related network sites based on the available migration paths from that site to other sites.

Comment: Related questions seem to be only tenuously linked to the original post. I'm all for suggestions to improve the quality of that list - not sure diluting the pool with questions from other networks would help without refining the process of selection.

Comment: As I understand, the score used for ranking is unchanged by the addition of other documents.  So if it were designed so that network questions knocked local questions off the "Related" list, then they'll knock off the lowest scoring questions (i.e., the least related).

Comment: Would be great if linked questions worked across sites to stay with (unless they already do?)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet