# Similar question search works better than actual search

Tags: feature-request, search, related-questions, similar-questions

I wanted to open a question titled "What's the best SQLite Cocoa library?". The suggestions told me that the question might be closed for being subjective, but also suggested some similar questions. The answer I found this way was better than the answers that I found when I searched using the search box. In fact, the question I found didn't even appear in the list from the direct search.

Is there some way to use the better search without opening a question? Is there a reason they're so different?

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool

Comment: It's too bad you didn't apply that here.

Comment: Haha, +1 for pithy comment. Sorry about the dupe!