# Add "Related Questions" type search capability to search box

Tags: feature-request, search, related-questions

I'd like a way to capture the "Related Questions" functionally when you ask a question in the search box at the top of the page. The only non-UI change I can think of is a specific search character(s) to tell the engine you're looking for a question title, so:

My proposal is to allow some specific character (such as "?") at the beginning of a search string to tell the engine you're looking for question titles. For instance, you might type the following in the search box:

> ?What do you need to program on a
>   boat?

The results would be the same as if you'd typed the same question into the Title field of a new question and got "Related Questions" results.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39720/issues-with-question-suggestion-and-search-algorithm-differences

Comment: You can also get the raw results with [such URL](http://stackoverflow.com/search/titles?title=print+hello+world) then parse it yourself.