# How does SO get the related questions when I ask question?

Tags: discussion, related-questions

When I complete my title of question, the related questions are listed below. I am confused how can SO select the questions, there are no key words or someting like that.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the words you have just typed in for your title as key words:-)

Comment: Good question titles are excellent search keywords.

Comment: but the problem is if there are many words in question, it is very hard to match.

Comment: @Alan I imagine they use stop words to only pick out the relevant words: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words

Answer (score 1):

Per Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39720/issues-with-question-suggestion-and-search-algorithm-differences/62337#62337),

> The /questions/ask page is the same as searching with intitle:1 , that is, it only searches title text exclusively.