# Does the search in "new question" work different than the "regular" search?

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues with question suggestion and search algorithm differences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39720/issues-with-question-suggestion-and-search-algorithm-differences)

It turns out I get better results when asking a new question than when searching for an answer.

Are these two searches different or is it just the way I phrase my search?

Answer (score -1):

It's the way you phrase your search. Try phrasing it like you're going to ask an answer.

Comment: This is not the reason. The exact same phrasing in both places produces different results.