# Difference between "Ask question" suggestions & search

Tags: discussion, questions, search, duplicate-suggestions

I am getting to different results when searching using the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) & Ask question suggestions ("Questions that may already have your answer")

Because each search is provided to help finding the proper required content/question asked.

Then why a difference is maintained?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39720/issues-with-question-suggestion-and-search-algorithm-differences http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94674/does-the-search-in-new-question-work-different-than-the-regular-search http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38054/improve-search-functionality