# Do you find that when you go to ask a question, you end up answering one?

Tags: discussion, related-questions

I would say more often than not, the "Related Questions" box that comes up after typing in a question title ends up with two things happening for me:

1. I find the answer to my question, despite having searched for it already. (maybe I need to start typing out my question in the 'Search' box to improve the quality of my manual searches!) Obviously, this was the intent of that Related Questions box and at least for me, it works very well... so Kudos!
2. I find one or two unanswered questions that I am able to offer an answer to; often because of things I have come across while trying to solve my issue before coming to SO to ask. Perhaps an unintended benefit of the "Related Questions" box, but it has definitely been a pattern for me.

I like how much that particular feature has improved my SO experience. So, as a pure discussion; does this happen to you, too?

---

EDIT: I suppose I might not really be capturing the intention of the `discussion` tag here all that well, judging by the -1 vote I got. I am at least assuming that my (frivolous though it may be) question was clear; "has this happened to you?", so I assume the -1 was due to subject matter.

Maybe the question will be closed if that is the case, which is fine by me; I consider -1 votes and questions being closed to be a chance to learn better how to operate within the community.

Comment: @Five Golden Rings - It's an interesting habit of mine that when I'm typing a title, subject, etc, I title case it out of habit. It's not always an appropriate habit, I know. (I fight myself doing it when posting tweets/FB status updates, even).

Comment: btw, my above comment was in response to Five Golden Rings editing my question from my original, in which I had "Title Cased" all the words. In his edit comment, he noted that Title Casing is of the Devil :p

Comment: I don't know whether this question is on- or off-topic (I'm rather new here), but I gave +1 because I learned some interesting things here.

Comment: @Mitch Schwartz & the other +1'er (Goran, perhaps?) Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Andrew here.

I was quite positively surprised when I started typing my first question, and all of the sudden a bunch of related already asked questions poped out. This is the best anti-duplicate mechanism I've ever seen so far. In several occasions it really did show me that my question has already been asked and answered, although I did try to find it before (admittedly, not thorough enough).

Comment: +1 That was one thing that hit me in particular; I was obviously not searching thoroughly enough, hence my idea to simply search on what I would title my question if asked, and perhaps leave out 'noise' words but nothing else. But this invites the question that maybe I should have asked here (and maybe would have found an answer to via RQ) I wonder if the search mechanism is the same for the search box and the RQ listing... hmmm!

Comment: @Andrew: the thing is that the mechanism behind duplicate matching seems to be either: 1) working much much better 2) using more words to match than what we usually type in search box.

Comment: I found a quick answer to that side question: They are different (RQ only searched from Titles) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool/27187#27187

Comment: Please tell me you found that question through RQ when typing this one :D

Comment: hehe... I found that question by typing a hypothetical question in the "Ask Question" form, and it was the first result. (Don't remember the question I typed now). Incidentally; that question was not among the first few results when I pasted that same question into the 'Search' box. heh