# Why is asking a question often the best way to find a question?

Tags: discussion, search, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)

The following series of events happened to me today for about the 100th time:

- I have a programming question I cannot answer.
- I search Stackoverflow for the right question and hope it has good answers.
- Finding none, I google, which often yields better stackoverflow hits (related: *why is that?*).
- I think more about the question, rephrase it, and repeat the above steps.
- Finally, I click "Ask Question" on the stack, and type the title for my question.
- Upon tabbing from the title, I find my question in the "Related Questions" section!

While this is a happy moment, I can't help but think that one of my six or seven searches should have found it for me. Has anyone else had the same experience?

Comment: It works here on Meta too.  ;)

Comment: That's hysterical. -1 for me for not finding this in the list :-)