# "Questions with similar titles" in "Ask Question" works better than actual search

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search, similar-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)

Please someone explain me why "Questions with similar titles" in "Ask Question" page works better than actual search?

I usually find my solution in existing answers using "Questions with similar titles" not search box.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon its cause of the way you search. I don't have such a problem, cause I ask questions when I'm searching. IT might help.