# Can the 'search' work as well as the new question subject line

Tags: feature-request, search

The new question subject line seems to be more effective than the search for finding relevant questions. I will often search and then think that there's not a question, write it out in vim, copy into the subject line and voila, it pulls up a question not found by searching. Is there a way to toggle that mode in search?

Or perhaps I'm missing something.

**edit 1**

I have seen this question [Related questions in "Ask Question" page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool) While I acknowledge that this exists, the ask functionality is just better.