# How does the duplicate search work?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

This search seems to work *much* better than the search bar at the top:

[image]

In fact, this is the way I normally search. Is there anyway the way this search works could be incorporated into the main search bar?

Comment: Closely related: [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)

Comment: @Fish, yep voted to close!