# Enhance search on site feature

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-suggestions

[This search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=bookmark%20vs%20favourite) returns zero results.

[image]

Just include the duplicate suggestions behavior in that as an option

Comment: Without the _"vs"_ you get 53 results

Comment: Search is different from similar question search. Search requires that all words are present, obviously "vs" isn't present in any post because leaving it out returns [53 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bookmark++favourite). Not a bug, just weird. Expect status by design.

Comment: What I usually do, is to search in google: [`site:meta.stackexchange.com bookmark vs favourite`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+bookmark+vs+favourite&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&oq=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+bookmark+vs+favourite&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.46876j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). This gives you way better results than the SE internal search.

Comment: In general, the search feature on Stack Exchange sites isn't very useful. I rarely use it unless I'm using specific [search operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). In most other situations, you're guaranteed to get more relevant results if you google `your search query site:SomeStackExchangeSite.com`.

Comment: @Ollie A workaround at best. The question explicitly asks about the SE internal search feature, so no, that won't be a good answer to the question.

Comment: Try the American spelling **favorite**. You now get 3 results. I don't know why this post got do many downvotes, the OP believed the 0 results must have been a bug. It's not that an unreasonable conclusion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Probably because it's a low-quality bug report.

Comment: @Mast Anything should I missed?

Comment: @Luuklag No, but it is duplicate. Can't we close our question as dupe

Answer (score 2):

Searching in the topbar:

[image]

Is different than searching in the question title.  Also, you'll notice that "favourite" is underlined in red, so while they are [both correct spellings](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/favorite-favourite/#:%7E:text=Favorite%20and%20favourite%20are%20both,is%20preferred%20in%20British%20English.), you get many more results in both search areas if you use the American "favorite", and/or take away the "vs".

**A workaround.**  I, as do others, use the Google search, `site:StackExchange sitename <place search query here>`, like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS778US779&q=site:meta.stackexchange.com+Question+and+answer+preview+is+wrongly+rendering+some+markdown&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwsJ2x_4vsAhVKdt8KHXHMD-8QvgUoAXoECAwQKA&biw=1600&bih=757) for example, when the Stack Exchange search gives less-than-useful results.