# related questions list should indicate if questions are answered/accepted

Tags: feature-request

When viewing a question, there's a "related" section to the bottom right of the page. It would be nice if this list showed the usual green number box indicating how many answers the question has and if an answer has been accepted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/add-icon-on-related-question-list-that-shows-answered-status (status-declined).

Comment: Can't yet vote up, but agree :) say a tick after the question would be great.